# What is the difference between \notag and \nonumber in align environment?

Tags: equations, align

I use `\notag` or `\nonumber` in `align` environment but there seems no any difference when display. What is the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Both are commands to switch off equation numbering. `\nonumber` is a kernel command, defined as:

```
\def\nonumber{\global\@eqnswfalse}
```

so you can use `\nonumber` without loading additional packages. `\notag` is defined in the `amsmath` package as `\nonumber`:

```
\newcommand{\notag}{\nonumber}
```

and then `amsmath` redefines `\nonumber` in the following way:

```
\renewcommand{\nonumber}{%
  \if@eqnsw
    \ifx\incr@eqnum\@empty \addtocounter{equation}\m@ne \fi
  \fi
  \let\print@eqnum\@empty \let\incr@eqnum\@empty
  \global\@eqnswfalse
}
```

which is a more safe version to use with `amsmath`. The definition of `\notag` will make `\notag` expand to the definition of `\nonumber` at the place of appearance, which is after `\nonumber` has been redefined. Hence (of course, when `amsmath` is used) the effect of both is the same.

Thanks to **egreg** and **tohecz** for their corrections.

Comment: This is incorrect: `\notag` is just the same as `amsmath`'s `\nonumber`, it is *not* the kernel `\nonumber` (notice that `\notag` expands `\nonumber`, which uses the *current* meaning, which is the new one).

Comment: @egreg: perhaps I am reading an old online version of `amsmath.sty`? Or am I misreading it? Let me check.

Comment: No, the version is correct. It doesn't matter whether `\newcommand{\notag}{\nonumber}` comes before or after the redefinition of `\nonumber`. When TeX finds `\notag` it replaces it with `\nonumber` and then expands this one to its current replacement text (which will be the new one).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `\newcommand{\notag}{\nonumber}` will make `\notag` expand to the definition of `\nonumber` at the place of appearance, which is after `\nonumber` has been re-defined. Hence the effect of both is the same, exactly as @egreg points out.

Comment: @egreg and tohecz: Ah, now I see; of course. I'll edit my answer.