# In the align environment, how to number only one of the lines?

Tags: numbering, align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selective numbering of equations with align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65207/selective-numbering-of-equations-with-align)

I would like to know, how to number only one specific line among many, in the align environment.

For instance, I don't want to number all the step of my equation, only the final result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selective numbering of equations with align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65207/selective-numbering-of-equations-with-align) See also [Make `align*` number the last equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66759/make-align-number-the-last-equation?rq=1), which is at least a little  related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `\notag` command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x=5\notag\\
y=2\notag\\
z=1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think we jumped here together. I changed  my answer to `\nonumber`.

Comment: @HarishKumar No problem. Today, I had this more than twice :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\notag` or `\nonumber` to get rid of numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
ax^2+bx+c
        & = 0\nonumber\\
ax^2+bx
        & = -c\nonumber\\
ax^2+bx
        & = -c
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \nonumber seems to be preferable. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48965/what-is-the-difference-between-notag-and-nonumber-in-align-environment