# Why is there multiply labels in this gather environment?

Tags: align, amsmath, labels, warnings, gather

The console says there are multiply labels in this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{gather}
    A \equiv X + Y \nonumber \\
\begin{align}
    &= C + D + E + F + G \nonumber \\
    &= E. \label{some label}
\end{align}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

What's wrong with this environment?

I need the last equation to be numbered, with a label, while the other lines shouldn't be numbered.

Comment: See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/15

Comment: @egreg OW!  So this is a bug with LaTeX!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think one should put an `align` environment into a `gather` environment, but you can use `aligned`. I think that `gather` and `align` should not be nested as they start their own math environment, but `aligned` is precisely made for having an `align` type math environment inside another math environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{gather}
    A \equiv X + Y \nonumber \\
\begin{aligned}[b]\label{some label}
    &= C + D + E + F + G \\
    &= E. 
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}

ANOTHER TEST
\begin{align}
\MoveEqLeft    A \equiv X + Y \notag \\
    &= C + D + E + F + G \notag\\
    &= E. \label{some label}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The label is assigned to the wrong line.  It's the last line that should be numbered and labeled.

Comment: @Cham Now it is.

Comment: I find it weird that my environment is giving some troubles, and that I need your more complicated solution.

Comment: @Cham BTW, you can also use just `align` with `\MoveEqLeft` from `mathtools`. As for your question in the comment, I think that `gather` and `align` should not be nested as they start their own math environment, but `aligned` is precisely made for having an `align` type math environment inside another math environment.

Comment: About \MoveEqLeft, could you give an example?  I'm not sure to understand your suggestion.

Comment: @Cham I added that to the answer. `\MoveEqLeft` is made for having a longer equation line inside an `align` environment.

Comment: Why (what advantages) the \notag, instead of \nonumber ?

Comment: @Cham `\notag` is shorter and can be found in the `amsmath` documentation, whereas `\nonumber` is a standard LaTeX command. You can find more details in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48967).

Comment: Apparently, both do exactly the same.  I prefer to use \nonumber all across my documents, for consistency and simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

It's a known problem, see https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/15

The manual of `amsmath` explicitly tells that `align` *can* be nested in `gather`, see page 26:

[image]

However a “register” is not cleared at the proper time and a spurious, but innocuous, warning of `There were multiply-defined labels` is issued; this happens in connection with `\nonumber`.

In my experiment, patching `\endalign` solves the issue.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\endalign}
 {\restorealignstate@}
 {\global\let\df@label\@empty\restorealignstate@}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{gather}
    A \equiv X + Y \nonumber \\
\begin{align}
    &= C + D + E + F + G \nonumber \\
    &= E. \label{some label}
\end{align}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```